# Angular: Toggle variable when clicking out of element

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm having trouble figuring out how to do something that I found pretty straight forward in jQuery. I've often made elements that when something is clicked, it opens up a menu, and then when clicked outside the element, the menu closes.

In jQuery, it was easy enough to do with something like this (with a `event.stopPropogatation()` in the element click:

```
$('html').click(function () {
    $('#someElement').hide();
});
```

I'm making a combobox directive as follows:

```
directive('combobox', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: '/angular/directives/combobox.php',
        scope: {
            'data': '=data',
            'search': '=results'
        },
        link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.showDropdown = false;
            $combobox = element.children('.combobox');
            $combobox.children('.results').css({ 'top': $combobox.outerHeight(), 'width': $combobox.outerWidth() });
            $combobox.children('.dropdown').css('height', $combobox.outerHeight());

            scope.toggleDropdown = function ($event) {
                $event.stopPropagation();
                scope.showDropdown = scope.showDropdown?false:true;
            }
            $('html').click(function () {
                scope.showDropdown = false;
            });

            scope.setBox = function (set) {
                scope.search = set;
            }
        }
    }
})
```

I tried to console out the value of scope in the HTML click function, and it shows the scope values, but when I try to change them, they remain unchanged. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, or if there's a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a `$scope.showDropdown` variable to your controller, and then `$watch` for it inside your directive.

Comment: If I'm adding logic for the directive outside of the directive, doesn't that eliminate the point of it being self-contained? Plus, how would I watch for the change? The same jQuery? Why would it work in the controller but not the directive link?

Comment: I'm not sure I would call your directive 'self-contained', as it currently listens to $('html') for clicks. As for watching, as well as your 'data' and 'search' attributes, you could add a 'isOpen' attribute, then use `scope.$watch('isOpen')` in your directive to control the open/close.

Comment: Well, I'd say self contained as the directive doesn't need code from the controller to work. Appreciate the advice; I'll give that a shot and see if other's have advice as well.